# Skinning, Bones, IK of character lost after Unity restart. Reproduceable

Tags: unity

After i properly rig my character for skeletal animation with IK and everything works as expected but I quit my editor and restart, all bones are gone, IK does not correspond to the limbs and nothing works.

It is reproducible. What can I do?

Image is after restart and nothing works.

[image]

Comment: Have the same :( Helps openning skinning editor do small change and click Apply. But you have to do it for each model. That sucks.